# Center logo in mobile header

Tags: css, wordpress

I need to modify the positioning of my logo on my mobile header. It needs to be cetnered inline with the other icons. I'm using Safari mobile inspector with my iPhone 6+ plugged in and I cannot seem to get it. I'm using the Porto theme for Wordpress and have checked all the theme options already.

Here is the [site](http://harvillnew.wpengine.com)

[image]

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all `max-width: 110px;` properties from `#header .logo` and then include the following code to your stylesheet:

```
.logo a img{
    width: 110px;
}
.logo{
    margin: 0 !important;
}
.header-main .container{
    padding-top: 0 !important;
}
```